# Trying to find a romance book about a girl who falls in love with a high ranking vampire and finds out she’s an angel

Tags: story-identification, novel

This is what I can remember from the book:

The girl is adopted and her and her rich friend is in (college?). One day she goes to study at a different friend's a house (a boy) and finds him dead or his apartment all bloody or something. She also sees a “dark figure” standing there who was the vampire she falls in love with and he was surprised that she could see through his glamour. For some reason he does take her to his big apartment and calls for his friend's help because she gets sick or poisoned or something like that.

They do end up falling in love and you also find out that she’s part angel. Her grandfather was an evil angel who got cast down to Earth and her father was his son, and her mother was a messenger angel that was sent to Earth to tell the main character's grandfather to stop making vampires or they would kill him. Her mother fell in love with her father and they had the main character.

Her mother already had a son from a previous arranged relationship with a war angel and he had taken the main character she was kid and put her in a adopted family to keep her safe from her grandfather and watched over her her whole life.

Her mother and father were mated and her grandfather separated them and earned her father's mind of her mother so that he would always feel her mother's suffering of getting drowned (where the grandfather put her in the middle of the sea) but wouldn’t know why he was seeing that.

A couple side notes is that she likes lacy underwear and her best friend is actually an artificial angel her grandfather was trying to make so that she could bear him a real angel son.

When her and her vampire boyfriend finally (mate?) he also gets a pair of wings and they can feel whatever their partner is feeling. The friend that died in the beginning is also an angel and that was all fake.

Yes, they have intercourse in a big pool with a waterfall.

This was through a course of like seven books.